# Max & Group by returning different results in Excel and Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Wrote a query returns the most recently updated record for each item for each day, in other words, Item 444222 gets 12 records each day and the query pulls the most updated one. Sometimes the records are inserted the day before, of, and after. When the query is run in workbench, I get the correct value, but in Excel PowerQuery it returns the earliest record. Is there a coding error on my part, or is it something else? Any help with this would be appreciated. 
record_type: varchar, date: date, item_number: int, cycle_id: int, scheduled_cap: int, insert_date: timestamp.

Query attached below.

```
Select record_type, date, item_number, cycle_id, scheduled_cap, max(insert_date) 
from db.all_cycles
Where date >= '2016-01-01'
AND record_tyoe = 'I' 
AND cycle_id NOT IN (40, 38, 39, 41, 53, 185)

AND item_number IN ('94850', '94858', '452917')

group by item_number, date, record_type
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Your query should not work in *any* database.  The `select` expressions are in compatible with the `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *filtering* not *aggregation*:

```
select ac.*
from db.all_cycles ac
where ac.date >= '2016-01-01' and
      ac.record_tyoe = 'I' and
      ac.cycle_id not in (40, 38, 39, 41, 53, 185) and
      ac.item_number in ('94850', '94858', '452917') and
      ac.insert_date = (select max(ac2.insert_date)
                        from db.all_cycles ac2
                        where ac2.date = ac.date and
                              ac2.item_number = ac.item_number and
                              ac2.record_tyoe = ac.record_type
                       )
order by date desc;
```